# memcpy fail to copy all data

Tags: c, memcpy

I encounter problem with memcpy in C. Here is the code :

```
typedef struct {
CPY_IM009_DEF
}message;

message msg;
```

with CPY_IM009_DEF is a struct in other files. Then I try this

```
char wx_msg_buf[8192];
memset(wx_msg_buf, 32, sizeof (wx_msg_buf));
memcpy(wx_msg_buf, &msg, sizeof (msg));
```

when I check the size :

sizeof (msg) = 2140

sizeof (wx_msg_buf) = 8192

But when I check the wx_msg_buf, memcpy only copy part of msg to wx_msg_buf (200 from 2140).
What I want to know is why does this happen?If more code required please tell me

Thanx you for the help.

Comment: I think we need to see the definition of CPY_IM009_DEF

Comment: You didn't show `msg` being initialized, so it is conceivable that it isn't ever set and `memcpy` is doing what it is supposed to, except that you are feeding it garbage source data.  When you changed the size of your buffer (in a comment to your question as an answer) it could have altered the layout of the memory in such a way tht the uninitialized data area appears to be more in line with what you expect to see -- probably bytes not being set to 0.

Comment: Actually msg was initialized, but since the code are too big I don't put it here.

Answer (score 3):

How are you checking? Simply printing the string or looking at it in a debugger? If the message has any '\0' characters in it. It will stop printing at the first one.

To see the whole thing, you can just loop through and print each character. Something like this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(wx_msg_buf); ++i) {
   printf("%02x ", wx_msg_buf[i]);
}
```

Comment: sizeof(msg) since that is what's used in the memcpy().

Comment: @Heath: Sure, I figured he may as well take a look at the whole buffer :-P.

Comment: I check it using GDB, put a break point then print both msg and wx_msg_buf

Comment: It's probably treating wx_msg_buf ad a C string is what Evan is saying.  Printing it in gdb (`print wx_msg_buf`) will take you only to the first null.  You need to dump the entire contents of the buffer to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me. The problem may be with the way you look at it. What is the layout of the underlying structure, and what tools to you use to get the observation about the 2000 bytes?

Comment: when I print the value in GDB it show the result like this :
(gdb) p wx_msg_buf
$1 = "0000L_NAME00000POSLH000FN_NAME", '0' <repeats 40 times>, "4800010120100101010100COM_HDR0B.MX_BUFFER", '0' <repeats 89 times>

Answer (score 0):

Check your source data and your result data in a debugger.

It is almost inconceivable that memcpy() has a defect, it's used so widely.

Comment: I know that's why I'm confused.I use memcpy() several time in the code, but only this line that have problem

Answer (score 0):

Try once; "memmove" instead of "memcpy"..
memcpy() is faster, but it's not safe for moving blocks of memory where the source and destination overlap. memmove() can be used to move memory in those cases.

So better use "memmove".. i think it will solve your problem

Comment: msg and wx_msg_buf are different variables. They do not overlap, so you don't get any additional safety with memmove.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I change :

```
char wx_msg_buf[8192];
```

into

```
char wx_msg_buf[2141];
```

and now the code work, still I can't understand why the previous won't work